# how to pass other arguments as a result of By.js

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, e2e-testing

I'm trying to use a javascript code to decide which selector to use for the rest of my e2e test, the issue is that I'm relying on [By.js()](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/by_exports_By.html#By.js) that should return an element or a list of elements.

PS: I've tried to send a callback-function as an argument to the By.js() function, but it didn't work.

`selenium-webdriver 4.0.0`

```
driver.wait(webdriver.until.elementLocated(webdriver.By.js(function (selectors) {
    let element = null;
    for (let i in selectors) {
        if (element = document.querySelector(selectors[i])) {
            return element;}
    }
    return null;
}, ["#e1", "#e2", "#e3"])), 10000, "no random element found"))
.then(element => {
    console.log(PRINT THE SELECTOR THAT WAS USED TO FIND THE ELEMENT);
})
```

Comment: Location for `selenium-webdriver 4.0.0`?

Comment: inside node_modules